# Angular app (ng serve) too eager to compile in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

Recently my Angular apps are too eager to be compiled when running `ng serve` while I'm modifying files in WebStorm. It just compiles even as I type leading to a bunch of errors (obviously as it compiles not finished work) and high CPU as it compiles the project pretty much constantly.

I checked WebStorm settings and in `SystemSettings / Autosave` there are checked only 2 options:

- Save files when switching to different app or terminal
- synchronize external changes ....

which seems to be correct to me.

Angular version is 12.2.10 but it does this for version 13 as well. Any hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE doesn't normally save files on each key pressing.
Features that can be responsible for auto-saving:

- Live Edit (that is active during JavaScript debug session)
- File watchers (if **Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher** is enabled in watcher settings)
- built-in HTML preview (if opened and configured to reload on change)
- some third-party plugins are known for causing such issues, as they save files to run analysis on the changes

Comment: thx, i gave disabled some plugins and it helped, it seems.

Comment: *have (typo.....)